# Can I create a custom criteria query like

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I have a legacy PostgreSql table that contains columns with multiple values. I want to select rows that contain any of the values in my search.

```
-- Example query
select * from stuff where ARRAY['Value A', 'Value X'] && regexp_split_to_array(thing, '\|');
```

Can I generate this type of where condition from Grails 2.5.1 GORM 4.x criteria query?

FYI: I have seen the "Grails Postgresql Extensions Plugin" but I can't change my column(s) definition at this time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `sqlRestriction` in a criteria to add arbitrary SQL conditions. It's mentioned at the [bottom of the node reference for `createCriteria()`](https://grails.github.io/grails2-doc/2.5.1/ref/Domain%20Classes/createCriteria.html).

```
Stuff.withCriteria {
    sqlRestriction "ARRAY['Value A', 'Value X'] && regexp_split_to_array(thing, '\|')"
}
```